# Python - unusual behaviour with custom tree

Tags: python, list, tree

I needed to sort a list in a very specific way by using a tree in a Python script, so I wrote my own quick TreeNode class. However, I have found very odd behaviour when appending a child to a node and I really cannot understand what is going on.

Here is the class:

```
class TreeNode:

    children = []
    identity = ""

    def __init__(self, node_id, c = []):
        self.identity = node_id
        self.children = c

    def get_id(self):
        return self.identity

    def append_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def remove_child(self, child):
        self.children.remove(child)

    def get_children(self):
        return self.children

    def walk(self):
        yield self
        for child in self.children:
            for n in child.walk():
                yield n

    def find_id(self, node_id):
        if self.identity == node_id:
            return self
        for child in self.children:
            found = child.find_id(node_id)
            if found:
                return child
        return None
```

What is happening is that when I append a child to the tree, the child's list of children is instantiated with length one, and that first element is a reference back to that same child. And, so, that first element in the children has a children list of length one too, also refering to the same node, and it goes on seemingly ad infinitum.

Here is a visualisation of the "tree" after just a single element has been appended to the root node...

[image]

I have no clue what is happening here and I hope that somebody else who is more familiar with Python might be able to enlighten me. It's been bugging me all afternoon!

Comment: That `c = []` in the `__init__` sure looks suspicious. Are you familiar with the "[Default Mutable Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)" trap?

Comment: I am not. I will google it now.

Comment: Can you share code how you create a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, node_id, c = []):
```

The problem is your `c = []`. Default arguments to functions are evaluated exactly one time in Python. So the first time you initialize a TreeNode and change `c`, that `c` will retain the changed value the next time you create a new TreeNode, because it's a list and they won't create new lists each time, they'll just keep referring to the exact same list. You'll be initializing the child node with the same `child` list that the parent had.

This is what you want instead:

```
def __init__(self, node_id, c = None):
    if c is None:
        c = []
```

This works because you're creating a new empty list every time you initialize a TreeNode. In the previous setup, you were modifying the exact same list every time, because of the issue Kevin linked to in his comment.

Comment: Thanks, this solves it. Totally new problem to me. Always something new to learn! I will accept as soon as SO will let me. Though perhaps the credit should go to Kevin.

Comment: @Luke Python is full of intricacies like this; I only learned about this problem recently, maybe a few days ago, so you're not alone there.